# Excel to accept negative Time

Tags: excel, time, subtraction, negative-number

How can I modify an Excel cell to accept minus time such as (12:30- in the format hours:minutes) , I want this so as to insert Employee monthly exceeded, expected hours (e.g. 00:30+ for July) or below the monthly expected hours (e.g. 01:33- for June).

Comment: Negative time really has no meaning in Excel. That's why you get ####### You need to change the format when adding or subtracting to General.

Comment: I know that it has no meaning in Excel, but for HR systems if you observe that (ex : total Employee working hours for June should be 160:30 hours but actual working hours are 160:00 so the rest time is 00:30-) such case should inserted in Excel .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option #1**

You could use this function:

```
=IF(A1-A2<0,TEXT(ABS(A1-A2),"[hh]:mm-"),TEXT(A1-A2,"[hh]:mm"))
```

The result would look like:
[image: difference negative time]

**Option #2**

[Microsoft says that you could do a switch to the 1904 Date System](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/182247#mt2):

> In Microsoft Office Excel 2003 and in earlier versions of Microsoft Excel, follow these steps:
>   1. Open, or switch to, the workbook.
>   2. On the **Tools** menu, click **Options**, and then click the **Calculation** tab.
>   3. Click to select the **1904 Date System** check box.
>   4. Click **OK**.
>
> In Microsoft Office Excel 2007, follow these steps:
>   1. Click the **Microsoft Office Button**, and then click **Excel Options**.
>   2. Click the **Advanced** category.
>   3. Under **When calculating this workbook**, click to select the **Use 1904 date system** check box, and then click **OK**.

Comment: This will convert the value to text. For any further calculations you need to  convert back to a number `=Value()`

Comment: To introduce a `+` sign the formula would become even bigger: `=IF(A1-A2<0,TEXT(ABS(A1-A2),"[hh]:mm-"),IF(A1-A2=0,TEXT(A1-A2,"[hh]:mm"),TEXT(A1-A2,"[hh]:mm+")))`

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are subtracting one date/time from another. Just format the cell with the answer as General. One day = 1.

`=A3*24` gives you the number of hours +/-

`=A3*24*60` gives you the number of minutes +/-

`=A3*24*60*60` gives you the number of seconds +/-

[image]

This works positive or negative.